# Error by passing variable from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know this question was already answered one million times but I'm becoming desperate with this code.

I have two files php files and I want to send a variable from a part written in JS to the other PHP file. So here's the code:

**carga_datos.php**

```
<script>
    function MyAlert() {
            var radio1 = $("input[name='inputTipoActividad']:checked").val();
            $.ajax({
                url : 'post.php',
                type : "POST",
                data: {'radio1' : radio1},
                dataType:'json',
                success : function(data) {

                    alert(data);
                },
            });
        }   
</script>
```

I'm calling to MyAlert() in a radio button form

**post.php**

```
<?php 
    $radio1 = $_POST['radio1'];
    echo $radio1;
?>
```

And I call post.php into carga_datos.php like this:

And this is the error I'm retrieving:

> **Notice**: > Undefined index: radio1 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\gis\post.php** on line 2

Comment: have you checked the ajax request by looking in your browser's network tab whether any value is actually being sent for "radio1" in the request? Then we can see if the problem is really server- or client-side.

Comment: Have you tested that `var radio1 = $("input[name='inputTipoActividad']:checked").val();` is correctly retrieving the radio button's value? Try console logging this before sending via AJAX to ensure it is ready to be sent.

Comment: Even if the variable was null, radio1 would still be set in `$_POST`, no?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that or send me a guide? Thank you

Comment: Can you try by removing `dataType:'json',` ?

Comment: @ iainn The AJAX post would fail if the radio1 value is not set.

Comment: yes, value of radio1 is correct. I checked that

Comment: Are you getting a value from `echo $radio1;` ? that message you posted is a warning that you've not checked that `$_POST['radio1']` is set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Not working removing dataType

Comment: I see `dataType` is the type expected in response from server not sent. Use `method` instead of `type` to set the HTTP request type.
See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @SergioBarbero can you show us full html page ?

Comment: @SergioBarbero are you geting an output from `echo $radio1`?

Comment: @WillParky93 Just the error, no output

Comment: Please try replacing `$radio1 = $_POST['radio1']; echo $radio1;`
with `var_dump($_POST);` and update with the response you get from the AJAX call in your Chrome network tab.

Comment: @SergioBarbero the notice can be removed by changing `$radio1 = $_POST['radio1'];` to `$radio1 = (isset($_POST['radio1'])) ? $_POST['radio1']:die('No post sent!');`

Comment: Yes if you are loading post.php without sending any AJAX data or setting the value of $_POST then the logic will fail. It may be useful to move all PHP that handles AJAX requests into a separate PHP file that you do not load directly in browser to avoid these issues.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay read the jquery ajax docs. The `dataType` setting is related to the _response_ type. Nothing to do with what is being sent to the server, which is the problem here. `contentType` would affect what is _sent_. But it's not set here and will therefore be the default, which should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

It seems you have used dataType "json" so it will expect a "json", if none is returned you will get undefined or an empty response.

If you remove dataType: "json" you should be able to retrieve the data just fine.

```
    function MyAlert() {
    var radio1 = $("input[name='inputTipoActividad']:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'post.php',
        method : "POST",
        data: {"radio1" : radio1},
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to check with "dataType: 'json'" still in your code, you need to return your PHP code like the following:

```
<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>
```

This will then either return your $_POST data or just an empty [] array.

// Old Answer for just true/false values

If you just want to see if the checkbox was checked or not to retrieve a boolean, please try the following:

```
var radio1 = $("input[name='inputTipoActividad']").prop("checked");
```

This will return TRUE or FALSE. If not wrong, if you use

```
$("input[name='inputTipoActividad']:checked").val()
```

it'll return "on" or nothing (might be wrong here though).

Tested it with the ".prop("checked")" and it worked for me.

Comment: I want to get the value of my form

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to remove "dataType: json" unless you will return a json format with PHP.